# Как перенаправлять всегда на кокнретную папку, кроме одного случая?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

Есть у меня в корне проекта папки `backend/index.php` и `frontend/index.html`

Как мне прописать в корне проекта в файле `.htaccess` правила, чтобы любые запросы в url отправлялись в папку `frontend/index.html`, а если в `url` начинается с `api`, то в `backend/index.php`? Пробовал по-всякому, но я не знаю `.htaccess` хорошо и поэтому всё не выходит.

Например вот это:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule (.*) /frontend/index.html?$1 [L,NC]

    RewriteRule /api /backend/index.php
</IfModule>
```

Направляет только на фронтенд. Причём там `new UrlSearcParams().toString()` показывает пустоту..

Answer (score 0):

> Направляет только на фронтенд. Причём там new UrlSearcParams().toString() показывает пустоту..

Вы делаете внутренний редирект, переадресация происходит на стороне сервера, тогда как JavaScript  видит только то, что есть в адресной строке браузера. Чтобы сделать внешний редирект, можно поставить флаг например `[R=301]` или напечатать полученный массив гет-параметров серверным скриптом в переменную JavaScript при выводе страницы.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !/api
    RewriteRule .* /frontend/index.html [L]

    Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} /api
    RewriteRule .* /backend/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]